# How to make selected nav button stay active

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created some javascript trying to keep a nav button active. I realise this has been asked a few times before but I think my code is fairly basic and I am trying to make it work if possible. My HTML looks like this:

```
<nav>
<ul class ="nav"> <!-- Niall Added-->

  <li id='active1' onclick = "doClick(1)"><%= link_to "HOME",   '/' %></li>
  <li id='active2' onclick = "doClick(2)"><%= link_to "MATCHES",   matches_path %></li>
  <li id='active3' onclick = "doClick(3)"><%= link_to "CAR POOLING",   car_pooling_path %></li>
  <li id='active4' onclick = "doClick(4)"><%= link_to "STATISTICS",   statistics_path %></li>
  <li id='active5' onclick = "doClick(5)"><%= link_to "MENTORS AREA", mentors_area_path %></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

And my javascript looks like this:

```
function doClick(x) {

if ( x == 1) {
     document.getElementById("active1").style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';

 }

 else if (x == 2) {

   document.getElementById('active2').style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
 }

   else if (x == 3) {

   document.getElementById('active3').style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
 } 

   else if (x == 4) {

   document.getElementById('active4').style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
 } 

 else if (x == 5) {

   document.getElementById('active5').style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
 }
```

}

However the button is not actually changing colour upon being clicked.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it works properly. But I suggest easier and more DRY solution with jQuery:

html:

```
    <nav>
        <ul class ="nav"> <!-- Niall Added-->
          <li class="element">Home0</li>
          <li class="element">Home1</li>
          <li class="element">Home2</li>
          <li class="element"">Home3</li>
          <li class="element">Home4</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

css:

```
    .element.active {
        background: #99C262;
    }
```

js:

```
    $(function() {
        $(".element").click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to go about your solution.

I would remove the id's from the lis you don't need them you can make things a lot simplier.

I have added an ID to the nav and removed the id's from the lis.

```
<nav>
<ul id="nav"> <!-- Niall Added-->
  <li><%= link_to "HOME",   '/' %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "MATCHES",   matches_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "CAR POOLING",   car_pooling_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "STATISTICS",   statistics_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "MENTORS AREA", mentors_area_path %></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I am using loops to look at all of the child elements of the navigation and apply the event, this keeps your HTML clean.

I am using the function to clear the color of all of the children then reapply the colour to the item that I clicked.

```
(function() {

    var nav = document.getElementById('nav');

    function handleClick(e) {

        for(var i = 0; i < nav.children.length; i++) {
            nav.children[i].style.background = 'transparent';
        }
       e.target.style.background = 'red'; 
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < nav.children.length; i++) {
        nav.children[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    }

})();
```

Check the demo here:
http://codepen.io/DanielTate/pen/KVPoYa

Obviously if you are navigating away from the page you will need to handle this in a different way, possibly looking at the URL.

Comment: @NiallL The CSS shouldn't matter, because of how CSS works JS will  overwrite it. Is your page changing the URL? Is there a network request changing the state of your page? There is possibly more going on here than simple CSS HTML and JS, I would recommend removing everything you don't need, get this working then put it back in piece by piece until you find what is breaking your code.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I will work at that. I tried to add the CSS as a comment here but I wasn't legible. I think all suggestions are great and should be working. As you have said the simple fact that nothing is changing upon me putting them into my code is indication that something else is going on. Strangely if I introduce an alert as part of the JS it works fine. It just won't apply the rest of the JS.

Comment: OK I have lost all hope of getting this to work. I have removed all CSS and tried everything I can think of but this just won't work for me. The button changes color for a split second but then reverts back to its inactive color then. At this stage I would take anything that differentiates the button that is active. Some sort of highlight CSS around the button that was last clicked perhaps? Or I am open to any suggestions. I think my issue is to do with the scaffold used to build the pages on cloud 9 but this is beyond me to troubleshoot at this stage of my education to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make sure your code is run on document ready.
See my example here using jQuery

```
.active {
  background-color: #99C262;
}

<nav>
<ul class ="nav"> 
  <li class="active">One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
</ul>
</nav>

$(function() {
  var all = $('ul li');

  all.on('click', function() {
    //clear
    all.removeClass('active');
    //set only this
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

});
```

[Example using jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/rodrigo/5oad65dh/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working:

CSS

```
   nav ul li a:hover {
   background-color: #080808;
   color: #ffbd10;
   transition: 0.5s;
   }

   nav ul li a.active{
   background-color:#080808;
   }
```

Html:

```
 <nav>
 <ul class ="nav"> <!-- Niall Added-->
 <li class="tab"><%= link_to "HOME",   '/' %></li>
 <li class="tab"><%= link_to "MATCHES",   matches_path %></li>
 <li class="tab"><%= link_to "CAR POOLING",   carpools_path %></li>
 <li class="tab"><%= link_to "STATISTICS",   statistics_path %></li>
 <li class="tab"><%= link_to "MENTORS AREA", mentors_area_path %></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </nav>
```

JS:

```
function tab_active() {
        var tabIndex = 0;
var url = location.href.toLowerCase();

if (url.indexOf("matches") > -1) {
    tabIndex = 1;
} else if (url.indexOf("carpools") > -1) {
    tabIndex = 2;
} else if (url.indexOf("statistics") > -1) {
    tabIndex = 3;
} else if (url.indexOf("mentors_area") > -1 || url.indexOf("opponents") > -1) {
    tabIndex = 4;
}

// Code using $ as usual goes here.
var $tabLinks = $(".nav .tab a");
$tabLinks.removeClass("active").eq(tabIndex).addClass("active");

$tabLinks.on("mouseover", function() {
    $tabLinks.eq(tabIndex).removeClass("active");
});
$tabLinks.on("mouseout", function() {
    $tabLinks.eq(tabIndex).addClass("active");
});
}
```